# JNI successfully builds corrupt library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, nmake

I have a library for Android, written in java and c++. It builds on build server correctly, works fine and takes about 80mb.

But when i build it on my machine, using either jom or nmake, the library takes 6mb and application crashes when trying to invoke functionality from that library. It seems that this behavior began after updating java itself. I suspect it doesn't link functions from .so file, and builds library just from java code, but there is no output from jom or nmake to support that.

msvs 15, jdk1.8.0_181, jre1.8.0_181, android-ndk-r16b